# Operation on an array returns NaN if array length is 1

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```js
Player.prototype.d2 = function(ratingList, rdList) {
    var tempSum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < ratingList.length; i++) {
        var tempE = this.e(ratingList[i], rdList[i]);
        tempSum += Math.pow(this.g(rdList[1]), 2) * tempE * (1 - tempE);
    }
    return 1 / Math.pow(q, 2) * tempSum;
};
```

This seems to be the bit in question.

Everything seems fine unless `ratingList`, `rdList` and `outcomeList` only contain one value. Then stuff gets set to NaN instead. I've tried changing the index to -1, changing the comparison to `ratingList.length - 1`, even tried it with a decrementing `for` loop, but it always seems to return NaN if the arrays contain only one value.

Is there any way (I'm sure there is -- I guess the question is how) to do away with the `for` loop and replace it with `Array.map()` or zip or any composition of those kinds of functions?

[You can see ALL of the code here -- it's about 60 LOC](http://jsfiddle.net/9LetB/)

Comment: And by "only contain one value" you mean: `ratingList = ["OneValue"]` or `ratingList = "OneValue"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `d2` function you have this line in `for` loop:

```
tempSum += Math.pow(this.g(rdList[1]), 2) * tempE * (1 - tempE);
```

So it is assumed that `rdList` is 2 elements at least, but you have only one for `bob`.

Maybe it have to be `rdList[i]`?

Comment: Yep, that's it.  Probably wanted rdList[i]

Comment: THANKS! On the other hand, now I feel stupid, lol. Still academically curious if anyone knows how to replace the loops with other constructs.